# Accessing a controller method's required roles/authorities from a filter

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-filters

Is it possible to retrieve a list of the roles/authorities required for a particular controller action/method in a Grails Filter?

Assuming the Spring Security Core (2.0.x) plugin installed and a Controller using @Secured annotations such as:

```
class PersonController {

    @Secured(['ROLE_MANAGER','ROLE_USER'])
    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond Person.list(params), model:[personInstanceCount: Person.count()]
    }

    @Secured(['ROLE_MANAGER'])
    def show(Person personInstance) {
        respond personInstance
    }
}
```

If a user navigated to the index action, the filter would get ['ROLE_MANAGER', 'ROLE_USER'] and if they navigated to show, the filter would get ['ROLE_MANAGER'].  I tried injecting the [objectDefinitionSource](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/63027adb3322ddd8e2e0ab8ced65b53983ec196f/SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy) into the filter and using `objectDefinitionSource.allConfigAttributes` like the following:

```
class MyFilters {

    def objectDefinitionSource    

    def filters = {
        all(controller:'assets', action:'*', invert: true) {
            before = {
                // get list of spring security roles required for the controller's action
                objectDefinitionSource.allConfigAttributes.each { println it }
                // additional filter behavior...
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

but as the method suggests, it displays all the roles defined in the app not just those specific to that action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
def ctrlClass = grailsApplication.getArtefactByLogicalPropertyName("Controller", controllerName).clazz
def roles = ctrlClass.getDeclaredMethod(actionName).getAnnotation(grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured).value()
```

It should return ['ROLE_MANAGER','ROLE_USER'] for your "index" action and ['ROLE_MANAGER'] for your "show" action